# how to copy directories from remote machines to localhost?

Tags: ansible, copy

In ansible playbook, fetch module only copies file from target machine to local.
copy/synchronize modules can copy directories/files from local to target machine.

Then how to copy direcotries from remote target machines

Comment: the remote target machines would be target for ansible, right ? Also if ssh connection is established between the host `delegate_to` can be used. `delegate_to` will copy the directories to the remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to ducumentation :
[synchronize – A wrapper around rsync](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html)

> mode(string) Choices: {pull,push}
>
> Specify the direction of the synchronization.
>
> In push mode the localhost or delegate is the source.
>
> In pull mode the remote host in context is the source.

Comment: As a sidenote: As a  consequence, synchronize localhost to localhost is not possible when not running explicitly on ``host: localhost``, I think.

Answer (score -2):

This is not specific to ansible but you can use `scp`:

```
scp me@my-host /path/to/remote/folder /path/to/local/folder
```

This will copy the folder from your remote machine to a local folder.

Comment: the OP is looking for ansible way. this should be last approach that should be used